# Got "No Books matches the given query" error even though the object exist on Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-forms

I got this problem where Django return "No Books matches the given query", even though the object exist in database.

For context, I want to create an update page without relying the use of URL.
First, here is my model :

```
User = get_user_model()
class Books(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
    )
    author_nationality = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Japanese')
    author_medsos = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='None')
    book_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        null=True,
        choices=BOOKS_TYPES
    )
    tl_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=True, 
        choices=TRANSLATION_BY
    )
    series_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=SERIES_STATUS,
        default=ONG
    )
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100) # source can refer to downloage page, example = https://www.justlightnovels.com/2023/03/hollow-regalia/
    reading_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=READING_STATUS,
        default=TOR
    )
    current_progress = models.CharField( # For tracking how many chapter have been read
        max_length=30,
        null=True
    )
    cover = models.FileField(upload_to='cover/', default='cover/default.png')
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)

class Review(models.Model):
    books = models.ForeignKey('Books', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    volume = models.IntegerField()
    review = models.TextField()
```

Before the user get to the update page, they first have to visit `/library` page,

```
{% for book in user_books %}
    <div class='lib-item'>
        <form method='POST' action="{% url 'core:update_library' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='hidden' name='book_id' value='{{ book.id }}'>
            <button type='submit'>
                <img src={{ book.cover.url }} width='185'>
                
                    <span>
                        {{ book.title }}
                    </span>
                
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Notice the hidden input? The idea is to pass the book.id to the next page, which is `/library/update`. Here is the page for `/library/update` :

```
{% block content %}   
<div class='content'>
    <h3>{{ book.title }} by {{ book.author }}</h3>
    <small> _id : {{ book_id }} </small>
    <small> id : {{ book }} </small>

    <form method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type='submit'>submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is the views.py for both page

```
@login_required
def library(request):
    user = request.user
    user_books = user.books_set.all()
    context = {
        'user' : user,
        'user_books' : user_books
    }
    return render(request, 'user_library.html', context)

@login_required
def update_library(request):
    user = request.user

    book_id = request.POST.get('book_id')
    print(f"book id : {book_id}")
    book = get_object_or_404(user.books_set, pk=book_id)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateBooks(request.POST, instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        context = {
            'book_id' : book_id,
            'book' : book,
            'form' : form
        }
        # messages.success(request, 'Library have been updated')
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('/library/update/')
        return render(request, 'user_update.html', context)
    else :
        context = {
            'book_id' : book_id,
            'book' : book
        }
        return render(request, 'user_update.html', context)
```

And the form using ModelForm :

```
class AddBooks(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        exclude = ["owner"]

class UpdateBooks(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        exclude = ["books"]
```

Now, when the user load the `/library` page, the page works fine. When user choose a book, they are redirected to `/library/update` with the book's id being passed with the use of hidden `input`. And the `/library/update` able to display the information about the chosen book correctly, including the id, object, title, and author. So the book's id should be present right?

But when the user submit the form, the page return an error : "Page not found (404) No Books matches the given query".

I am confused as to why the error says there is "No Books matches the given query". I have check Django admin page and the object exist. Even the `/library/update` is correctly displaying the information about the books, so the book object should exist. But when submitting the form, the books does not exist.

Does anyone have any ideas about this error happens?

Thank you

EDIT :
I find a new clue about the the missing book_id
So when `/library/update` is rendered, book_id exist, that's why the HTML able to display book_id with `{{ book_id }}`.
Now, I was checking the terminal when the page is rendered. Notice there is `print` statement in `views.py`? When the page is rendered, my terminal output `book id : 14`. So the `book_id` exist when the page is rendered.

But when the form is submitted, `print` is triggered again and printed out `book id : None`.

I don't know why, but `book_id` exist when the page is rendered, but missing when the form is submitted.

Below is screenshot of my terminal, red arrow when the page is rendered, and green arrow when the form is submitted.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to use URL for updating the book? You mean you don't want to pass the `book_id` as the URL argument?

Comment: @McPherson Yes, that's what I meant by that. That's why I use button instead of a to direct user to the next page.

Comment: I do see the input passing the id when you POST from `/library` but when you POST from `/library/update` i don't get how  `book_id` gets into the body.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by "`book_id` gets into the body". What do you mean by "body"? 
Also I've added new context for this problem, if you could please check them for more clue. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you make a POST request in your `/library` page when you want to just direct a user to an update page? Given there's no side effects that should be a GET request. Relating to that you should just have the Book ID as part of the URL for the update view. Also `UpdateBooks(request.POST, instance=book)` doesn't make much sense given `book` is an instance of `Books` and `UpdateBooks` is a model form for `Review`??

Comment: Yes I can put the ID to URL, I just want to do it this way so the URL doesn't contain any information about the back-end even if the information is not sensitive. Also for your second point, I though I can do that because I use `form.instance.owner = user`, with form is for `Books` form. Are they different? I guess I need to read the docs again.